# Can users and forms from two free plans be "merged" into one paid plan?

Tags: cognito-forms

I'm currently using Cognito Forms as a free plan user and my colleague is using Cognito Forms as a free plan user. We plan to upgrade to one of the higher plans but would like to know if we can insert the already existing users and the forms created in their free plans into a upgraded plan so that we do not have to rebuild all the forms that were already created under the free plan?

Answer (score 1):

Forms can be easily copied between organizations in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) in two ways:

1. Under Form Settings, enable template sharing, save changes, and use the template sharing link to copy a form into another organization.  This approach works even when the other organization is not associated with the first in any way.
2. As long as you are a user of both organizations, use New Form - Copy Form to copy forms from one organization into another.  If you have two organizations on the Individual plan associated with two different users, just upgrade one, invite the user from the other organization, and use this user account to copy forms into the paid organization